# How can I edit lists and have their edits be displayed?

Tags: python

I have to make a flight reservation system that allows viewing and editing of reservations, but i am unable to figure out how to make my code to allow that. this is my code so far but i can not figure out how to edit the list and then have it print with names in the reservation view. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def mainMenu():
  print("="*69)
  cstr = "Welcome to Airlines"
  print (cstr.center(69,'='))
  print("="*69)
  cstr = "CA Travel System 1.0 by "
  print (cstr.center(69, '#'))  
  print("="*69)
  print("option: Reserve First Class seat(rf), Reserve Coach seat(rc),Print(P),Change Reserve(C), Quit(q)")
  print("="*69)
  print("Enter 1 to buy a seat or Enter 2 to quit")
  mainAction= input("What would you like to do? ")
  clientNam = input("What name will be used for the reservation? ")
  seatLet = input("What seat letter would you perfer? Seats A and D are window and B and C are aisle(A-D) ")
  seatNum = input("What row number will you prefer? Rows 1-4 are first class. Row 5-15 are coach (1-15) ")







  print("     ""======First Class=======")
  print("        ""==A==" "       ""==B==")
  l1 = [1, "| Open |", 2 , 3, 4]
  l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
  l3 = ["Open", "Open" ]
  l4 = ["Open", "Open" ]
  l5 = ["Open", "Open" ]
  l6 = ["Open", "Open" ]
  l7 = [ "Open", "Open","Open", "Open"]
  l8 = [ "Open", "Open","Open", "Open"]
  l9 = [ "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open"]
  l10 = ["Open", "Open","Open", "Open"]
  l11 = ["Open", "Open","Open", "Open"]
  l12 = ["Open", "Open","Open", "Open"]
  l13 = ["Open", "Open","Open", "Open"]
  l14 = ["Open", "Open","Open", "Open"]
  l15 = ["Open", "Open","Open", "Open"]
  l16 = ["Open", "Open","Open", "Open"]
  l17 = ["Open", "Open","Open", "Open"]

  if seatLet == 'A' and seatNum == 1:
    l3[0] = clientNam
    if seatLet == 'A' and seatNum == 2:
      l4[0] = clientNam
      if seatLet == 'A' and seatNum == 3:
        l5[0] = clientNam 
        if seatLet == 'A' and seatNum == 4:
          l6[0] = clientNam





  print(l1[0],"     ", l3[0], "     ", l3[1])
  print(l1[2],"     ", l4[0], "     ", l4[1])
  print(l1[3],"     ", l5[0], "     ", l5[1])
  print(l1[4],"     ", l6[0], "     ", l6[1])
  print("   ", "=======Coach Class========")
  print("       ""==A==" "        ""==B==","        ""==C==" "       ""==D==")
  print(l2[0],"    ", l7[0], "        ", l7[1], "    ",l7[2], "      ", l7[3])
  print(l2[1],"    ", l8[0], "        ", l8[1], "    ",l8[2], "      ", l8[3])
  print(l2[2],"    ", l9[0], "        ", l9[1], "    ",l9[2], "      ", l9[3])
  print(l2[3],"    ", l10[0], "       ", l10[1], "    ",l10[2], "    ", l10[3])
  print(l2[4],"    ", l11[0], "       ", l11[1], "    ",l11[2],"    ", l11[3])
  print(l2[5],"    ", l12[0], "       ", l12[1], "    ",l12[2], "    ", l12[3])
  print(l2[6],"    ", l13[0], "       ", l13[1], "    ",l13[2], "    ", l13[3])
  print(l2[7],"    ", l14[0], "       ", l14[1], "    ",l14[2], "    ", l14[3])
  print(l2[8],"    ", l15[0], "       ", l15[1], "    ",l15[2], "    ", l15[3])
  print(l2[9],"    ", l16[0], "        ", l16[1], "    ",l16[2],"   ", l16[3])
  print(l2[10],"   ", l17[0], "       ", l17[1], "    ",l17[2], "    ", l17[3]) 

while True:
    mainMenu()
```

Comment: better use one list instead of variables `l1`, `l2`, etc. You will have access `seats[0][0]`

Comment: or keep it in dictionary so you could use letter `seats["A"][0]` and then you can access element with `seats[seatLet][seatNum]`